# Search for next element when next page is loaded

Tags: reactjs

I am currently programming a product guide package. Where a user can start a guide and the elements are highlighted step-by-step. But in the steps there is a possibility that the user is redirected to a new page.

My problem is that the hook that i programmed searches the next element when a state is updated so it will search the element before the new page is loaded.

Is there a way to let my hook search the element when a new page is loaded or something like that?
Not looking for an interval.

[custom hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVhcN.png)

Comment: You can generally listen for/use an effect to detect page changes, but without some detail about your code and how it works that's pretty much all we can give you as an answer. Please edit your question to include which (if any) router you're using, and ideally add a simple example of the problem.

Comment: If you can create stackblitz sample or something like that to replicate your issue, that will be helpful to understand and provide solutions.